# Freezer malfunction

Tags: appliances

My GE built-in side by side 15 yrs old.is playing games. One they everything is melting. When throw them out after few days it starts freezing again. Is it worth repairing?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Unfortunately, any answer to this question will be a matter of opinion. Please [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: might want to clean the coils in back really well. they get dirty over time and often decrease performance before mechanical parts wear out.

Answer (score 1):

**Simple.** Any refrigerator or freezer that's 15 years old is (almost always) not worth repairing for the simple reason that it is far more expensive to OPERATE than a new, efficient unit will be. If applying this logic, do pay attention to the efficiency of the new unit, as they vary quite a bit, but as a rule, past 7-10 years the operating cost of an older refrigeration unit is doing you no favors, so replacement is definitely advisable if it's malfunctioning. If your electric rate is very low this applies somewhat less strongly for refrigeration units that are working fine, and if it's high it applies more strongly - but for older units *in need of repair*, it applies broadly.

Comment: I disagree on the energy aspect. I replaced a 12-years old fridge recently. The new one uses the same amount of power/energy as the 12-years old model.

Comment: "you probably have a faulty sensor or **control board triggering defrost.**" +1 @Fizz - the answer's still "no" though.